# How to display website status code to user?

Tags: storyboard, swift5, http-status-codes, urlsession

Im trying to get the status code of a website and display it to the user. My code is :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let dataURL = "https://google.com"
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: dataURL)!)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [self] (data, response, error) in

        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            let responsecode = httpResponse!.statusCode
            ServerStausLabel.text = String(responsecode)
            
        }
    }
```

But for some reason it just displays the default text of the label.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: As Donmag said, I set up the task, but I didn't run it(`task.resume`).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up the `.dataTask`, but never actually execute that code...

```
    let dataURL = "https://google.com"
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: dataURL)!)
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [self] (data, response, error) in

        // properly unwrap the optional response
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let responsecode = httpResponse.statusCode
            ServerStausLabel.text = String(responsecode)
        } else {
            print("Request Failed")
        }
        
    }
    
    // this executes the request
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks!
Regards Alexander